# Ionic 6 / react issue with fetching data from the server

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, ionic-framework, fetch-api

I’m having an issue with fetching the data from the server in the android applications
versions :
“@ionic/react”: “^6.0.0”,
“@ionic/react-router”: “^6.0.0”,"
“react”: “^17.0.1”,

Everything works just fine when I open the app in the browser, but when trying to preview it in Android Studio Emulator, the data seems not to be fetched, without any specific error thrown. I’m using a @redux/toolkit as a state management, tried fetching the data with axios and fetch, both approaches led to the same result.
It seems like response object is present (with status 200), but no actual data can be used.

At first, I used Pixel 2 API 30, then advised to change to Pixel 4, no changes. Also tried on real android device, still behaviour is the same.

Images:

> Not working in android studio

[image]

> Working as intended in web app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I resolved the issue.
The issue here is that I set a base url to package.json file as:

```
"proxy":"https....."
```

And then, in the file above, in fetch, I was adding just a permalink.
This solution works for web app, but for some reason it's not working on android.
Now I changed the code inside fetch to whole link, and it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update - always useful for future users who have the same problem.